CSS file doesn't apply to all pages, except index.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- Started 19.04.2024-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\styles.css">
</head>



I'm working on a website project using HTML/CSS. I decided to use a common CSS file for all pages. In this context, all the pages, except index.html (home page), must be in a folder called "pages". The CSS file, mentioned above, does not apply to these pages when they are in the folder, even if the reference is correct (<link rel="stylesheet" href="css\styles.css">). But when I put the pages in the main folder, the CSS file DOES apply to them. I'm new to HTML & CSS, so some help would be appreciated.
I tried to put the CSS file in the same folder as the pages, but it didn't work. I expect that the CSS file is in the "css" folder and the pages are placed in the "pages" folder. At the same time, the CSS file would apply to all the pages.

Questions should show the code in question.

Please share the code of your HTML file and if you can also share a screenshot of how your project is organized (folder and file structure).

Try href="\css\styles.css" instead of href="css\styles.css"

Do not post code as an image

Welcome! Please do not post pictures of code. Copy and paste your code into the question using the stack snippet tool or backticks.

Paths are relative unless they start with a slash /
If you have html files in the "pages" directory, then the path "css/styles.css" refers to pages/css/styles.css
What you probably want is <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
(note: the web uses forward slashes / not back-slashes \ — backslashes may work for you on MS servers, but the web specifications say to use /)
